# Libgdx Actor.setBounds() relative to Actor.x and Actor.y and etc

Tags: java, libgdx

Im having trouble of setting bounding rectangle position thats why i ask this.
When I set the bounding rectangle position of an object of type [`Actor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html), it seems the coordinates i passed to `[setBounds(x,y,with,height)`][2](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setBounds-float-float-float-float-) is relative to the x and y of the [`Actor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) object. Is this true?

And also, when I use `Group.addAction(Actions.MoveTo(x,y,duration))`, it seems the [`Actor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) object dont update its x and y.Is this also true? If yes, how can i update it? I dont know what to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting bounds updates the x and y of the `Actor`.

Each actor's x and y can be thought of as their local x and y, but their actual position on screen is the sum of their x and y and the x and y of every ancestor (owning `Group`).

When you move a `Group` (which is itself an `Actor`), you are moving its x and y. This does not modify the x and y of its children, but their on-screen positions change because of the above reason.

So if you want to move an `Actor` to a specific position on screen without moving any of its ancestors, you should only change its local x and y. Therefore, you need to subtract the sum of all its ancestors' x and y from your target world (aka stage) position.

```
static final Vector2 TEMP = new Vector2(); //reusable to avoid GC

...

TEMP.set(targetX, targetY); //world(aka stage) coordinates of target position
myActor.stageToLocalCoordinates(TEMP); //subtract ancestor positions to get local target position
myActor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(TEMP.x, TEMP.y, duration));
```

Comment: did you mean If I use the setBounds() of the `Actor`, it will then change its x and y with the parameter x and y passed to the method?
Thanks for enlightening me with the x and y of the `Actor` when adding it to the `Group`.